# Coldfusion StructDelete creates blank value

Tags: cookies, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I'm using Codlfusion 9's StructDelete() method to remove a value from a cookie. But after using

```
StructDelete(cookie,"selector12")
```

I'm getting a value of *[empty string]* for **cookie.selector12** despite *deleting* it

This is the code I'm using:

```
<cfdump var="#cookie#">
<!--- kill any existing selector cookie when looking at a profile --->
<cfset structDelete(cookie,'selector#URL.clk#')>
<cfdump var="selector#URL.clk#">
<cfdump var="#cookie#">
```

To give the following output:

[image: Screen shot of cookie cfdumps]

Does StructDelete actually just set blank values? Or have I missed something obvious and simple... again

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The behavior of StructDelete() when applied to the COOKIE structure pushes the following header to your browser:

```
Set-Cookie SELECTOR12=;expires=Wed, 14-Dec-2011 10:06:02 GMT;path=/
```

which in turn will (for the remainder of the life of that request) produce a browser cookie with a blank value -- which mimics the behavior you're seeing when calling cfdump on that COOKIE structure.

This is simply a side-effect of dealing with the COOKIE structure, which in reality, wraps access to your browser's cookies--and is therefore limited by how cookies are defined/managed in web-browsers.

Comment: Thank you Holmes. Living up to your name there. I guess I'll have to work around that then, cheers.

Comment: Would help to use `<cfcookie name="selector#URL.clk#" expires="now">` instead of or in addition to the `structDelete`?